# manage.py syncdb error, postgres_psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, psycopg2, django-manage.py

I'm trying to install a shopping cart plugin for django but having a problem when I run manage.py syncdb.

When run, it installs 4 tables, then I'm getting the following error message:

> File
>   "(mypath)/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py",
>   line 44, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(query, args) django.db.utils.DatabaseError:
>   NUMERIC scale 127 must be between 0
>   and precision 10

I'm guessing that there is most likely a problem with the models.py but I don't know what line to look at.

has anyone ever run into anything similar?

Comment: Let use know what fields the models.py defined in the shopping cart application. Perhaps whoever wrote that never tried running it on a PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a numeric field with an invalid scale defined. Did you perhaps mix up scale and precision?